# opencv - is facial recognition used to detect non face objects?

Tags: opencv

Can (or maybe should) I use facial recognition software to detect non-faces?  For example, let's say I'm trying to find a can of soda in a picture of a bedroom.  If I use the haartraining algorithms on many pictures of cans of soda, will the facial recognition feature then find the can of soda in a picture of a bedroom?

Comment: Normally all kinds of algorithms can be twisted and mis-used to accomplish things.  Only way to find out for your particular case is to make a small demo project.   If anyone says 'no' they're probably wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. Those algorithms are based on extracting features from training sets. If you pass them faces the will be good at detecting features from faces. If you pass them cans they will be good at detecting cans.

A different idea is when you specialize an algorithm on a specific object by restricting the search, but haar are not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to face-*detection* not face-*recognition*.
In general, face detection works on discriminating appearance or textures within the face area. They also implicitly assume a mostly planar object.

You can use the same classifiers to detect other mostly-flat objects which are discriminated by appearance, for example, facial features like eyes and mouth, book covers etc.

Soda cans are cylindrical, so you may have to use multiple overlapping rotated view of each can to get it to work.